# how to print contents of PYTHONPATH

Tags: python

I have set path using

```
sys.path.insert(1, mypath)
```

Then, I tried to print contents of PYTHONPATH variable using os.environ as below

```
print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
```

but I am getting error as

```
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

How can we print contents of PYTHONPATH variable.

Comment: Obviously that means you don't have python path set in your machine.

Comment: @thavan shouldn't sys.path.insert set the PYTHONPATH variable?

Comment: One thing to note: sys.path is initialized from a number of locations, one of which is the environment variable PYTHONPATH. However, updating sys.path does not update PYTHONPATH.

Comment: @Drt no it shouldn't - it's set in the environment before Python runs... it's something Python can pick up and use... Most child processes can't affect the parents environment anyway... So as I mentioned in my answer - what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Drt I don't think so. Python searches modules in $PATH and well as in $PYTHONPATH. But they are different. $PATH is common for all programs.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I suggest not to rely on the raw PYTHONPATH because it can vary depending on the OS.

Instead of the PYTHONPATH value in the `os.environ` dict, use `sys.path` from the `sys` module. This is preferrrable, because it is platform independent:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

The value of `sys.path` is initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default (depending on your OS). For more info see

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: there must/should be some common variable for `PYTHONPATH` in all platforms. If it differs, I guess we are better of using sys.path then.

Comment: Why do you want to use the raw PYTHONPATH while `sys.path` is based on this variable plus some other default dir (depending on your OS) ? See http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path for more info.

Comment: I thought it is other way around, i.e. PYTHONPATH depends on sys.path. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 9):

If `PYTHONPATH` hasn't been set then that's expected, maybe default it to an empty string:

```
import os
print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH', ''))
```

You may also be after:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Comment: I have tried defaulting to an empty string. And then did `sys.path.insert(1, mypath)`. But no change. I am still getting error for `print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])` as keyerror.

Comment: @Drt what are you actually trying to do?