# Create a virtualenv from another virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

Can we create a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) from an existing virtualenv in order to inherit the installed libraries?

In detail:

I first create a "reference" virtualenv, and add libraries (with versions fixed):

```
virtualenv ref
source ref/bin/activate
pip install -U pip==8.1.1     # <- I want to fix the version number
pip install -U wheel==0.29.0  # <- I want to fix the version number
```

Then:

```
virtualenv -p ref/bin/python myapp
source myapp/bin/activate
pip list
```

I get:

```
pip (1.4.1)
setuptools (0.9.8)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

How to get my installed libraries?

**Similar question**

I saw a similar question: [Can a virtualenv inherit from another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538675/can-a-virtualenv-inherit-from-another).

But I want a isolated virtualenv which didn't use the referenced virtualenv, except for libraries installation. So, adding the specified directories to the Python path for the currently-active virtualenv, is not the solution.

**Why doing that?**

Well, we have an integration server which builds the applications (for releases and continuous integration) and we want to keep the control on libraries versions and make the build faster.

**Create a relocatable virtualenv**

I think I could use a [relocatable virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#making-environments-relocatable), that way:

1. create the **ref** virtualenv
2. make it relocatable: ``virtualenv --relocatable ref```

For "myapp":

- copy **ref** to **myapp**

What do you think of this solution? Is it reliable for a distribuable release?

Comment: Create a second virtualenv and then `pip install -r <(/path/to/other/pip freeze)`?

Comment: You're right, I can install the requirements again. But if we can only copy the libraries, it can go faster.

Comment: What do you think of the "Create a relocatable virtualenv" solution?

Answer (score 11):

You can solve your problem by [using .pth files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html). Basically you do this:

```
virtualenv -p ref/bin/python myapp
realpath ref/lib/python3.6/site-packages > myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/base_venv.pth
```

After doing this and activating `myapp`, if you run `pip list` you should see all the packages from `ref` as well. Note that any packages installed in `myapp` would hide the respective package from `ref`.

Comment: Works with environments created using the built-in `venv` module, too. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: With Python 3.6 (from the rh-python36 SCL for CentOS 7), this works as described, but even though `pip list` shows packages from `ref`, if some software not under my control tries to use `pip install` to install one of the packages that is in `ref`, instead of saying it's already installed, it actually tries to install it.  Using `--exists-action` doesn't seem to help.  I suppose this may be useful behaviour in some cases, but not mine!

Comment: I think the issue I described with `pip install` trying to install packages that are already in `ref` is due to https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8695 pip is bundled in virtualenv, and virtualenv 20.0.30 includes a version of pip that suffers from that bug.

Comment: This handles searching for packages quite well but does not handle the command line PATH to handle python installed utilities in the virtual env. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

You may `freeze` list of packages from one env:

```
(ref) user@host:~/dir$ pip freeze > ref-packages.txt
```

Then install them:

```
(use) user@host:~/dir$ pip install -r ref-packages.txt
```

Comment: No, I don’t want to re-install the libraries, just copy existing ones (if possible).

Comment: So, what's the difference between "re-install" and "just copy"? I this case pip won't download them, just unpack the same libraries to an other directory.

Comment: Well, libraries with binaries (like lxml) run some build during installation…

Answer (score 0):

when you install the second virtualenv you have to add `--system-site-packages` flag.

```
virtualenv -p ref/bin/python myapp --system-site-packages
```

Comment: The ``--system-site-packages`` installs the libraries of the system Python, not the ones of the referenced virtualenv.

Comment: but the "system" should be your virtualenv

Comment: I’ve done this test too but it fails. I’ll retry that on my build server. I hope ``virtualenv`` is not too old…

Comment: Tested doesn't work for me either. pip version 8.1.2

Comment: I agree, it doesn’t work. I've tested on OS X. => it copies the system site-package, not the libraries of my newly created virtualenv.

Comment: I'm sad to find this doesn't work anymore. It seems like such a great solution for the problem, but I concur, not working in virtualenv 15.1.0, pip 10.0.1 either.

Answer (score 0):

The `pip` version `1.4.1` was bundle with an old version of `virtualenv`. For example the one shipped with Ubuntu 14.04. You should remove that from your system and install the most recent version of `virtualenv`.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

This might require root permissions (`sudo`).

Then upgrade `pip` inside the virtual env `pip install -U pip` or recrete the env.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved differently. With use of `PYTHONPATH`. First we create `ref` virtaulenv and install all needed packages here

```
$ virtualenv ref
$ source ref/bin/activate
$ pip install pep8
$ pip list
> pep8 (1.7.0)
> pip (8.1.2)
> setuptools (26.1.1)
> wheel (0.29.0)
```

Then we create second virtaulenv `use`.

```
$ virtualenv use
$ source use/bin/activate
$ pip list
> pip (8.1.2)
> setuptools (26.1.1)
> wheel (0.29.0)
```

And now we can set our `PYTHONPATH` in this env to include ref's directories

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=PYTHONPATH:/home/path_to/ref/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/home/path_to/ref/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
$ pip list
> pep8 (1.7.0)
> pip (8.1.2)
> setuptools (26.1.1)
> wheel (0.29.0)
```

As you see this way you just reference installed packages in ref's environment. Also note that we add this folders at the end so they will have lower priority.

**NOTE**: this are not all folders that exists in `PYTHONPATH`. I included this 2 because they are main ones. But if you will have some problems you can add other ones too, just lookup needed paths with this method
[how to print contents of PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486469/how-to-print-contents-of-pythonpath#18486534)