# Terminal says, that “successfully installed openpyxl 6.2.2“ but I can't import it in IDLE ; why? (python, beginner)

Tags: python, terminal, module

I am a total beginner in terms of programming. Currently, I am working with this book https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/appendixa/. 
In chapter 13 I need to install the `openpyxl` module. I did it exactly as the book told me to do, and my terminal confirms that it is installed. The same way I installed my `pyperclip` module ( which worked), but this time, every time I try to import it, it tells me, no module named `openpyxl`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import openpyxl
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

I have the newest version of python, and I tried `openpyxl` `2.6.2`, or `2.6.1`, but it is always the same.

I hope someone can help me, in another forum It was suggested to download Pycharm or Anaconda, but this is nothing that the book requires, and I have to stick to the instruction ( it is a university work).

Thank you!

Comment: Just to be sure, did you restart `IDLE` after you installed the module?

Comment: IDLE is probably using a different copy of python than you installed the module into.  [printing `sys.path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18486534/1358308) (inside IDLE and the command line) might give a clue as to what's going on.  also note that there are many ways of "installing a package" and  how you do this matters, updating the question describing what you did would help us suggest something more relevant.  also version numbers are much better than "the newest version of python"